# Why are the Xi baryons called "cascade" also?

Tags: particle-physics, history

Between the Lambda, Sigma, Xi, and Omega baryons, only the Xi family has an alternate name - *cascade*. This must be a result of the "particles zoo" and my guess is that the particles cascade in the accelerator is related. Why is this family the only one with this "unconventional" name?

Comment: Do minimal due diligence: the Ξ ⟶ Λ π ;   π⟶  2γ ; Λ ⟶  π p;  π-⟶ μ νbar;  μ ⟶  ...  could this be evocative of something?

Comment: @CosmasZachos No.

Comment: Taking the horse to the water, how could a cascading decay make him drink?

Comment: Go to the heavier baryon section of your PDG booklet. Are there famous baryons there that  decay to the cascade Ξ, so, cascade with a vengeance? But they lost the chance to be called cascade....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [first observation  paper](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.2.215):

> Neutral Cascade Hyperon Event
>
> Luis W. Alvarez, Philippe Eberhard, Myron L. Good, William Graziano, Harold K. Ticho, and Stanley G. Wojcicki
>
> Phys. Rev. Lett. 2, 215 – Published 1 March 1959

Has the world Cascade Hyperon in the title

And in this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperon)

> Ξ0 and Ξ− are also known as "cascade" hyperons, since they go through a two-step cascading decay into a nucleon.

If the discovery paper did not mention the new particle as Ξ ( I do not have access to the PRL) it is the same reason as the J/psi double name, two different namings, the "cascade" part honoring the first discovery.

Ξ is the next unused letter after Λ , μ being used for muon, and ν used for the neutrino.

Answer (score 0):

That one's easy: the Greek letter for "Xi" is $\Xi$, which looks like a three-step cascade.

Comment: Cascade is a stream or sequence of things. How does the Greek letter look like a cascade? Any source?

Comment: @user1803551 actually I don't have a source as I believe the name has a folk origin; it's just a "well known fact".  See http://nyfalls.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Seneca-Cascade-Mills-Falls-01.jpg for an example of how a three-step cascade can look like the three levels of $\Xi$.

Comment: Cascade is also the word used for the collection of small waterfalls as a stream goes down a slope that is not sheer.